# Set of independant vectors spanning a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a set of $n$ independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ where $2 < n < m$

My understanding is that these vectors do not form a basis as $n < m$, but do they span a plane in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: They span a plane going through the origin in $\mathbb R^m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will span an entire $n$ dimensional subspace (hyperplane) of $\mathbb{R}^m$ since they are independent.

Comment: So then in this case, since n>2, it spans both the n-dimensional subspace and the 2 dimensional subspace? Is it inclusive for all subspaces with lower dimensions or is it only spanning the n-dimensional subspace. Thanks for the response

Comment: @AbdullaKubba In general if you have $n$ independent vectors you can choose any $k$ of them to form a $k$ dimensional subspace so if $n>2$ then any two independent vectors will span a two dimensional plane.

Comment: @AbdullaKubba I'm assuming what you're asking is whether or not an $n$-dimensional subspace $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$ with $n > 2$ (that does not span $\mathbb{R}^m$) contains ALL subspaces with lower dimension. The answer is no; since $U$ does not span $\mathbb{R}^m$, we can always choose one or more vectors that are not in $U$ and create a new subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $U \cap W = \{0\}$.